# Ищу контрол с раскрывающимеся элементами (аккордеон)

Tags: delphi, gui, delphi-xe7

Возникла необходимость компактно разместить на форме большое количество таблиц (`TstringGrid` и `TValueListEditor`). К ним так же можно добавить `TRadioButtonGroup`.

Не раз видел, как это сделано в различных программах:

[image: Например здесь]

Хотел сделать так же, но не смог найти информации по этому поводу.

Comment: Кстати, уточните, VCL или FMX?

Comment: Хотел ответить по существу, но как увидел второпях принятый ответ, расхотел.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: А что вы собственно хотели ответить "по существу", если принятый ответ отвечает на поставленный вопрос?

Comment: @KromStern есть множество подобных компонентов. И в большинстве случаев, "родные" компоненты не являются лучшими с точки зрения usability.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: И что же вам мешает запостить лучший ответ и получить за него больше плюсов и побудить автора вопроса отметить его принятым? ;-)

Comment: З.Ы. Я предпочитаю родные компоненты, т.к. с ними нет проблем при установке и меньше при смене версии.

Comment: @KromStern автор уже принял ответ. Наверное, ему ровно столько и нужно. Будь я на месте автора, я бы старался как можно дольше держать подобный вопрос открытым, дабы собрать побольше экспертизы.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: Ваше право. И все же SO это коллективно наполняемая и поддерживаемая база знаний, а не помощь конкретным авторам.

Comment: @KromStern База знаний? Нет, не слыхал. _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers_. Автор задал вопрос, через полчаса принял ответ. Вывод: это ровно столько, сколько ему нужно. (Заранее извинюсь за то, что не смогу продолжить эту дискуссию.)

Comment: "С вами вместе мы создаем библиотеку подробных ответов на любой вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такой VCL контрол - называется CategoryPanelGroup
[image: CategoryPanelGroup]